# Datatable error in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data of null

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

My datatable appears to be fully functioning - the filtering and sorting of all my columns work, but I still get this error in my console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of null(…)`

Here are the most important parts:

notifications_datatable.rb

```
class NotificationsDatatable
  delegate :params, :h, :link_to, :content_tag, to: :@view

  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      draw: params[:draw].to_i,
      recordsTotal: total_records,
      recordsFiltered: notifications.total_entries,
      data: data
    }
  end
```

index.html.slim

```
table#notifications.dataTable.table.table-hover.table-nomargin.dataTable-tools.table-bordered.dataTable-custom.display data-source="<%= notifications_url(format: 'json') %>"
  thead
    tr
      th style="width: 94px;"
        = t('.client_id')
      th = t('.request_type')
      th = t('.applicant_name')
      th = t('.organisation')
      th = t('.sent_at')
      th data-orderable="false" 
        = t('.actions')
    tbody

javascript:
  $('#notifications').dataTable({
    responsive: true,
    PagingType: "full_numbers",
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: $('#notifications').data('data')
  });
```

If I expand the TypeError in my console I see this javascript and the `ajaxData` part has a red curly line underneath.

```
else
{
  // Object to extend the base settings
  oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( $.extend( baseAjax, ajax ) );

  // Restore for next time around
  ajax.data = ajaxData;
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
ajax: $('#notifications').data('data')
```

to:

```
ajax: $('#notifications').data('source')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line in `jquery.dataTables.js`:

```
// Restore for next time around
ajax.data = ajaxData;
```

To:

```
if (ajax && ajaxData) {
  // Restore for next time around
  ajax.data = ajaxData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
ajax: $('#notifications').data('data')
```

To:

```
ajax: {
  url: $('#notifications').data('source')
}
```